# Tree tapping in the UK - Time and legalities

Tags: food, uk, foraging, forests

Is it legal to tap trees on public land in the UK? I'm thinking of tapping sycamore trees in a local wood on an overnight trip in the spring.

Also, am I correct in the assumption that the last week of March would be a good time for the trip?

Comment: What do you mean by "public land"? Almost all land in the UK is owned by someone.

Comment: @Liam the wood is owned by the Woodland Trust but is open to the public

Comment: @Liam and now I know foraging is allowed on their woods! https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/visiting-woods/things-to-do/foraging/foraging-guidelines/ thanks for the question, now to see if it someone knows when I should be looking

Comment: I was going to write an answer, but then it occurred to me, [I don't know what's involved in this??](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14096/how-do-you-tap-a-tree-for-sap)

Comment: I thought it might be more invasive than that. hmmm, it's a tough one. Possibly worth asking the woodland trust directly?

Comment: @Liam I've tried contacting them before and haven't had a response :(

Comment: Is tapping a tree even practical in the UK? I thought you needed an extended period of subzero temperature, which is rare in the UK.

Comment: @DJClayworth it has been done for centuries in the UK, but the practice died out as with many wilderness skills

Comment: See [Is it practical to tap a tree for syrup on an overnight stop?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions) the answer is no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading online, I have found that there is no hard and set rule for knowing when to tap, but in the second half of March you should check trees on a regular basis (every day or so) by doing the following.

> Simply take a sharp point (I used the tip of the drill) and at about a
>   meter from the ground drive it in past the bark layer, typically 6mm
>   is fine. Give it a little wiggle up & down to loosen the fibres. Now
>   the moment of truth, if the sap is running it will form a droplet
>   within 30 seconds or so. If this doesn’t happen simply revisit the
>   tree every few days at this time of year.

Source: [Sycamore tapping](https://www.woodland-ways.co.uk/blog/wild-food-diaries/sycamore-tapping/)

Comment: Very cold nights and rather warm days are best for tapping the sap from trees. Once the tree starts to bud the sap will change taste.